# Understanding .NET data-related objects

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

Can someone explain in simple English, or point me to such an explanation, the role of each of the objects/controls needed to connect my `GridView` (or some other control) to a SQL table? There is a (excuse me if I get the names wrong, I am doing this from memory) `DataBinder`, `DataSource`, `DataSet` and I think there are others.

Specifically, I am trying to figure out what classes I would need to create/implement in the following scenario:
I have a C DLL that has functions for accessing data in it's own custom binary file format. It is sort of like a custom format for a database. I am writing a `C#` wrapper for the DLL which will allow me to use the custom files' data with regular `.NET` tools, such as binding to controls.

Thank you.

P.S. If it makes a difference, I am using WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Data Binding and Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx)**